Handling sidekiq service refresh
I am using this linux unit file for our sidekiq service:
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq low
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/backend/current
Environment="RAILS_ENV=production"
ExecStart=/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.9/wrappers/bundle exec sidekiq -C /var/www/backend/shared/config/sidekiq_low.yml

ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID

KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=86400

User=deploy
Group=deploy
UMask=0002

Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

# if we crash, restart
RestartSec=1
Restart=always


SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq_low

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

It works well, however, as we release new changes frequently, we need to restart the sidekiq service to spawn a new process with the new source code changes reflected.
The issue is that the workers sometimes takes hours to finish the job, that's why I sent USR1 signal:
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -USR1 $MAINPID

to gracefully wait the old processes to complete its work, but how to apply a hard timeout for those old processes before they should finally killed ?
I expect that when restarting the server, there will be new process running and old ones waiting to finish its work.
would the TimeoutStopSec=86400 apply the actual killing for those stuck processes?
how can I see those old processes?
systemctl status will not expose any stuck process
sudo systemctl status sidekiq-low@1974.service
● sidekiq-low@1974.service - sidekiq low
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sidekiq-low@1974.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-07-10 13:31:14 UTC; 2h 5min ago
   Main PID: 143529 (ruby)
      Tasks: 39 (limit: 18829)
     Memory: 540.4M (peak: 541.5M)
        CPU: 5min 57.873s
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-sidekiq\x2dlow.slice/sidekiq-low@1974.service
             └─143529 "sidekiq 6.5.12 backend [0 of 30 busy]"

Enlightenments are appreciated!

Sidekiq 7.3 supports Iterable Jobs, which allow long-running jobs to be restarted cleanly. That's your best investment.
https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Iteration

Starting with v7.3, Sidekiq allows jobs to declare themselves as Iterable. This means that the job can be decomposed into a sequence of elements to process; Sidekiq can stop and restart the job anywhere within this sequence using a cursor. This makes deployments with long-running jobs safer and cleaner, as long as those long-running jobs are Iterable.


Thank you, any recommendation for sidekiq 6.5.12?
